# Include margins in flex calculation?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've this fiddle:

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/rOvpqL

```
<div class="r1"></div>
<div class="r2"><button>toggle</button></div>
<div class="r1 target"></div>
```

Where I have 3 divs inside a flexbox, each div has a margin bottom.
One of these divs can toggle (hide/show).

The problem is that the first div should not change its size theoretically, but in practice it does.
I think the problem is flex not taking in account margins.

Is there a solution using flex?

Comment: Do you mean "change its *size*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the flexbox-layout is missing 10px when you're removing the bottom element (corresponding to the element's margin-bottom) .

You can overcome this adding  `flex-basis: 10px` to `.r3`. that will compensate the missing 10px.

### [pen](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/EVLEOq)

Comment: I don't want `.r1` to have a preset height. I just want it to not change when I toggle the 3rd element.

Comment: It's okay the default value, the problem is the behavior when I switch from 2 to 3 elements.

Comment: Well you should edit your answer, the one you provided is not the solution